# String reference check return true in my unit Test

Tags: c#

Below is my test case. Both string are different object yet the my test case pass.

I am expecting them to fail. Because they are different objects.

```
 string string1 = "Hello World";
    string string4 = "Hello World";
    Assert.AreSame(string1, string4);//Will return true
    Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(string1,string4));
```

Comment: what is the testing framework that is being used?

Comment: MSTest Framwork

Comment: Duplicate/Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112610/referenceequals-working-wrong-with-strings -tl;dr  compile time constants

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does string works in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794835/how-does-string-works-in-c)

Comment: Strings are saved in Table by CLR and if it is going to save string that already exists it will just return the link to the existing string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReferenceEquals working wrong with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112610/referenceequals-working-wrong-with-strings)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compiler will create one "object" for equal hardcoded strings.

But if you create strings dynamically

```
var string1 = "Hello World";
var name = "World";
var string2 = "Hello " + name;
Assert.AreSame(string1, string2); //Will return false
Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(string1,string2)); // Fail
Assert.AreEqual(string1, string2); // Pass
```

[String.Intern Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a
>   table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to
>   each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in
>   your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a
>   particular value only exists once in the system.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing strings. If objA and objB are strings, the ReferenceEquals method returns true if the string is interned. It does not perform a test for value equality.

In the following example, s1 and s2 are equal because they are two instances of a **single interned string**. 
However, s3 and s4 are not equal, because although they are have identical string values, that string is not interned.

```
String s1 = "String1";
String s2 = "String1";
//string is interned

String suffix = "A";
String s3 = "String" + suffix;
String s4 = "String" + suffix;  
//string is not interned
```